# Get selected value from MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple form with php and get values from the database. There is a dropdown box for membership types (normal and gold). I am trying to populate the selected dropdown value from the database. (member_type value)

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members");    
while($read = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

$MemName = $read['member_name'];
$MemType = $read['member_type'];

echo '<td><input type="text" name="mname" id="mname" value="'.$MemName.'"></td>
<td>
<select>
<option value="Normal">Normal</option>
<option value="Gold">Gold</option>
</select>
</td>
';
}
?>
```

Comment: There isn't a question here.

Comment: very basic concept. No debugging provided.

Comment: what exactly is the problem? does $MemName echo out ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two current solutions can both be improved upon, in my view:

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members");        
?>

<?php while($read = mysql_fetch_array($sql)): ?>
    <td>
        <input
            type="text"
            name="mname"
            id="mname"
            value="<?php echo $read['member_name'] ?>"
        >
    </td>
    <td>
        <select>
            <option
                value="Normal"
                <?php echo $read['member_type'] == 'Normal' : 'selected' : '' ?>
            >Normal</option>
            <option
                value="Gold"
                <?php echo $read['member_type'] == 'Gold' : 'selected' : '' ?>
            >Gold</option>
        </select>
    </td>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

What is different here?

- Importantly, HTML is not trapped inside `echo` statements. See how much easier it is to read? You don't need to worry about escaping quotes, or alternating between single and double quotes.
- The `<select>` menu structure is added only once - it is rather inefficient to have it in code several times, each with a different item selected. Imagine how awkward it would be to maintain if you had more menu items - an additional `else` clause for each one!
- HTML elements are spread over several lines if that makes them more readable. Note that this has always been a valid way of expressing HTML.
- PHP mode is entered only for the page set-up (the first half) and where there is dynamic content to render.
- The assignment of variables didn't really add anything, so I've used the array assigned inside the loop
- Since the while loop arguably is part of the template layer, I have switched from brace form to colon form, which is a popular standard. I think it is more readable, since adding `}` inside a PHP tag is not very visible inside HTML.

Nota bene:

- If `$MemName` comes from user input (or indeed any data you render) make sure you escape it using `htmlentities()`, otherwise you could introduce an XSS vulnerability.
- The variable name `$sql` is arguably not ideal - the return value of the query function is a database result - SQL is its *input*. I would suggest using `$result` or similar here.

Comment: Welcome @Dejavu, glad it is of assistance.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$currentMembership = 'Gold';
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members");    
while($read = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

    $MemName = $read['member_name'];
    $MemType = $read['member_type'];

    echo '<td><input type="text" name="mname" id="mname" value="'.$MemName.'"></td>
    <td>
    <select>
    <option value="Normal" ' . ($MemType == 'Normal' ? ' selected' : '') .'>Normal</option>
    <option value="Gold"' . ($MemType == 'Gold' ? ' selected' : '') .'>>Gold</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    ';
}
?>
```

Comment: Would work (+1) but I tend to recommend against trapping large blocks of HTML in `echo` statements, as it becomes unwieldy. See my answer for an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

Put if on your MemType

```
<?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members");    
    while($read = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

        $MemName = $read['member_name'];
        $MemType = $read['member_type'];

        echo '<td><input type="text" name="mname" id="mname" value="'.$MemName.'"></td><td>';
        if($MemType == 'Normal') {
            echo '<select>
            <option value="Normal" selected>Normal</option>
            <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
            </select>';
        }else if($MemType == 'Gold') {
            echo '<select>
            <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
            <option value="Gold" selected>Gold</option>
            </select>';
        } else {
            echo '<select>
            <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
            <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
            </select>';
        }
        echo '</td>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: @Dejavu: bear in mind there is excessive repetition in this code. It is better to have one menu, and then to add `selected` tags optionally where they apply.

Comment: Do you have an example for it? Thank you